# RegExp checking for sign only if there is text afterwards

Tags: regex

I have some cases, which I need to filter with a `regex`. The values which need to be filtered are listed below:

```
// These should be catched
123456_Test.pdf
123456 Test.pdf
123456.pdf

// These shouldn't be catched
123456Abcasd.pdf
123456-Abcasd.pdf
123456_.pdf
```

The current regEx looks like this:

`(\d{6,7})((\_| ){0,1})(.*)\..*`

The problem here is, that the latter 3 are also matched. To give you a short overview, whats wrong with the 1st "wrongly" matched strings:

The 1st capture-group has to consist `6-7` digits. (Also the capture-group is needed in the end). **If** there are letters *after* these numbers, there *has* to be a whitespace or underscore. The 1st example of the "shouldn't be catched" shows this. The entry is invalid, since there are letters **after** 123456 without the needed sign.

The last entry isn't really important, just there for convinience.

What am I missing? How do I adjust my regex in a way, that I can check for signs, only if there are letters following a number-chain?

Comment: Try [`^(\d{6,7})([_ ][A-Za-z].*)?\..*$`](https://regex101.com/r/B7QJ9c/1)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much. U want to add it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(\d{6,7})([_ ][A-Za-z].*)?\..*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/B7QJ9c/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(\d{6,7})` - Group 1: 6 or 7 digits
- `([_ ][A-Za-z].*)?` - an optional capturing group #2: a `_` or space followed with a letter and then any 0+ chars as many as possible, up to the last
- `\.` - `.` on a line
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this perl solution works for you.

```
> cat regex_catch.dat
123456_Test.pdf
123456 Test.pdf
123456.pdf

123456Abcasd.pdf
123456-Abcasd.pdf
123456_.pdf
> perl -ne ' print if m/\d+(([ _])[a-zA-Z]+| [a-zA-Z]*)?\.pdf/ ' regex_catch.dat
123456_Test.pdf
123456 Test.pdf
123456.pdf
>
```